# Which/ That/ Present Participle

Tags: translation, gerunds, relative-pronouns, medical

I'm working on the translation of a product packaging.

> Uses:
> Boosting liver function which helps cleanse blood plasma, the liquid portion of blood which/that accounts for 55% of its volume.

- Would it be better to use "benefits" in place of "uses"?
- Is it true that when saying the uses of a product, infinitives are preferred to gerunds (in this context, using "boost" instead of "boosting")?
- Could you please tell me if this sentence sounds fine with two *which* in a sentence or should I substitute the latter one with *that* or the Present Participle "accounting"?
- Is the use of "boosting" grammatically and medically correct as I've found out that "improving liver function" is more commonly used?
- The original version literally says "cleanse blood plasma", I've googled this phrase and the result is replaced with "cleanse your blood". Are they the same thing?

Comment: Knowing whether the product is a supplement sold in supermarkets and/or on the net  or if it has actual medicinal properties  makes a huge difference in the choice of words.

Comment: Thanks @Mari-LouA, I'm helping out my friend with her translation of a kind of herbal tea that she's selling online.

Comment: Then it's entirely up to you (and your friend) how to phrase the packaging. I might add that somehow using the bare infinitive "boost" gives the impression that it is a proven benefit, to my ears it sounds more *factual* than "boosting". On the other hand, you might need to consult https://ec.europa.eu/food/food/labelling-and-nutrition/food-supplements_en if you are selling the tea mainly as a supplement in Europe.

Comment: I use '' boosting'' as I think it would be grammatically wrong to say '' Boost liver function which helps cleanse blood plasma, the liquid portion of blood which/that accounts for 55% of its volume.'' Is it ok to use boost in place of '' boosting'' in this sentence?

Comment: Yes, in advertising language the bare infinitive is perfectly acceptable and you wouldn't need to add "uses". *Boost/increase/improve your concentration levels* sounds more dynamic than their gerund equivalents. Don't ask me why, it's probably subjective.

Answer (score 1):

Blood and blood plasma are not the same thing; your text explains that blood plasma is only a component of blood.

Logically, cleaning a component would clean blood as a whole, but I'm no doctor. Absent a clarification from a medical professional, it's best to stay consistent with your info and not let Google's algorithm edit your content.